# Scala generics usage for methods + json4s parsing

Tags: scala, generics, json4s

I am not sure if this is achievable and I have a very basic understanding of how generics work in scala. But I was wondering if this is possible.
Say I have a method:

```
case class Person(id:String,name:String)
case class Student(id:String,name:String, class:String)

    def convertToJson[A](fileName:String):{
     //read file
     parse[A]
    }
```

Is it possible to write this generic method which would parse the json based on the type of class I send when I call the convertToJson method?
Something like:

```
convertToJson[Student](fileName)
convertToJson[Person](fileName)
```

BTW the above code gives me a :

> No Manifest available for A. error.

Using json4s for parsing.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will convert a JSON string to a `case class`

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

def convertToJson[T](json: String)(implicit fmt: Formats = DefaultFormats, mf: Manifest[T]): T =
  Extraction.extract(parse(json))
```

Once this is defined you can parse appropriate strings to the required type:

```
case class Person(id: String, name: String)
case class Student(id: String, name: String, `class`: String)

val person = convertToJson[Person]("""{"name":"Jane","id":45}""")
val student = convertToJson[Student]("""{"name":"John","id":63, "class": "101"}""")
```

Note that this will ignore JSON data that does not match fields in the `case class`. If a field is optional in the JSON, make it an `Option` in the `case class` and you will get `None` if the field is not there.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. On a side note is there a way to deal with nulling out case when we have bad data? Say throw an exception or something?

Comment: @Achilleus If you have bad data the `extract` will throw an exception. You can let the caller handle that, or wrap the `extract` call in a `Try` and return a `Try[T]`, which is perhaps more standard in Scala.

Comment: Actually, it won't throw an exception in the situation when we are dealing with nested json and an object in it say has a field spelled wrong. It will just null that object and move on.  I was wondering if we can somehow specify it to fail or throw an exception instead of nulling it out.

Comment: Can you give an example of this? If I rename one of the fields from the JSON string I get `MappingException: No usable value for <fieldname>`.

Comment: Ah actually, it throws the exception for case classes. But I am using an Avro specific record case class. Its a case class that extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase. But somehow it serializes to null in this case.

Comment: Posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381927/json4s-serialization-of-string-to-avro-specific-record-class

Comment: is the `Manifest[T]` actually needed?